# Pass multiple variables to AJAX onchange select

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am looking at this script from W3schools.com (Ajax, PHP and Mysql)
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
<option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
<option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
<option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
</select>
</form>
<br />
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

This shows a simple select with 4 values.

And this is the PHP script.

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', '*', '*');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("ajax_demo", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Hometown</th>
<th>Job</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Hometown'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Job'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Now I understand what it does and how it works, but let's say that I want to pass 3 more variables to the PHP script, when someone changes the value of the selectbox, how do I do that??

Comment: By changing the query string of the getuser.php call, which in turn means changing the onChange function or adding more of them.  Alternatively changing he onChange function to select the values from each form field by ID.  As an aside, NEVER post username/passwords in questions.  Even if you post up "test"/"demo" ones, it's easy to accidentally post real ones if you get into that bad habit.  If this is something you are doing from scratch, would consider looking at a framework to simplify this i.e. jQuery to help with cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: What if I wanted to send something like a date (not todays date) and a time. 
So I would have to change this code? 

xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);

If I wanted to pass a variable called d or t.
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true"&d="+date,true);
Something like that?

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/ - what if `$_GET["q"]`value was `1'; drop table <sometable>; --`?

Comment: Something like that, see the answer Starx just posted, however you still need to get the variables into your function.  Give it a try and see what happens, it's not like the world will end if you don't get it right first try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from my comments, here's an example that takes the values from 2 selects, and submits an ajax call when both are filled in

```
// Notice the arguments are gone at the moment
function showUser() {
    // Retrieve values from the selects
    var u = document.getElementByID('userSelect').value;
    var g = document.getElementByID('groupSelect').value;

    if (u=="" || g == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    } 

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?u="+u+"&g="+g,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And then the basic form

```
<form>
    <select name="users" id="userSelect" onchange="showUser()">
        <option value="">Select a person:</option>
        <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
        <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
        <option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
        <option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
    </select>
    <select name="groups" id="groupSelect" onchange="showUser()">
        <option value="">Select a group:</option>
        <option value="a">Aerosmith</option>
        <option value="k">Kiss</option>
        <option value="l">Led Zeppelin</option>
        <option value="m">Metallica</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

This is not a fantastic option though, and as mentioned would recommend that you into using a framework such as jQuery ( http://jquery.com/ ) as you will be able to spend more time on the logic rather than ensuring browser compatibility

However you go about it though, it doesn't hurt to experiment so just give some things a try and see what happens (so long as you aren't deleting live data, anyway)

Answer (score 0):

In order to send mutliple values, you have change your query string accordingly.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
```

To, something like

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str+"&nextvar="+value1,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help better

```
    <script>function showUser(str) {  if (str == "") {
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
return;  } else {    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);

xmlhttp.send();  }}function shUser(str1) {  if (str1 == "") { document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
return;  } else {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?p="+str1,true); 
xmlhttp.send();  }}function sheUser(str2) {  if (str2 == "") {    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";    return;  } else {   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?r="+str2,true);

xmlhttp.send();  }}
```